# How to configuration of Test Server of Sagepay including redirection URI?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, opayo, asp.net-webpages

I have created an E-commerce based web application in Asp.Net(web forms) and integrate Sagepay server and it redirects to the Live URL on a test mode so I am not able to check that I have checked in my code that I have also enabled the Is Test Mode but it properly redirect with order and pricing but on a Test server but after successful payment in Test mode it redirects to that.

FYI: I have configured the application on the local system and set that in test Sagepay.

**Framework & Technology**: .Net Framework(v4.5), Vb.Net

**Tool**: BVcommerce

[image: Test server Home Page URL]

[image: Sage Pay Server Setting]
Is there anywhere I have to set the Redirect/Return URL or any configuration please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the URL to SagePay within the `NotificationURL` parameter which you post to SagePay to construct your Transaction Registration message.  Here's the full documentation to what your Transaction Registration POST : https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-server/api-reference/transaction-registration

Comment: Thanks, @PeteAUK I have checked the notification URI, and in that there is the only a relative path of success or failure. So in this case what I have to check.

Comment: The `NotificationURL` should be a fully qualified one (as per the documentation I linked).  That means an absolute URL and not a relative one.

Comment: Thanks, @PeteAUK I have checked and attach my Sagepay server options in question but still, it won't work. Can you please help me in this case? Even I try the same URL in both modes.

Comment: Are you able to post up the actual content of the POST prior to you performing the post?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you. Can you explain briefly?

Comment: Basically in order to help diagnose the problem, we need to see a copy of the actual data that is being POSTed to SagePay.  You can either log the data that gets posted or the easier way would be to POST to a local page and dump it out.  Sadly I'm not a .net dev so can't help on the code front.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not sure how to retrieve the content of the POST prior to sending it?  One alternative may be to post the actual code of your form above and the file that handles sending this to SagePay

Comment: Yes I have try to contact Sagepay currently.

Comment: Don't think I'm explaining myself as well as I could be.  Please post up all of the raw code that you're using (so the content of the form and anything that handles data).  I believe there may be a field not being sent correctly so this would help diagnose the problem.